# Store many values in a variable, if possible

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Wondering if anyone can help me, I'm trying to create a program that adds up the total amount of all the prices entered for each book, for as long as the do/while loop keeps looping, but all I have so far is that every time the loop restarts it deletes the previous assigned variable value! Can anybody steer me in the right direction? I'm just beginning with java so my knowledge pool is pretty low.

```
String surname, firstname, email, cfn, btitle, finished;
double pno, nochild, cage, noboks, costbook=0, totalcost, averagecost, price;




            k = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print("Welcome - What is your Family surname?");
              surname = k.next();
             System.out.print("What is your own first name?");
             firstname=k.next();
             System.out.print("What is your email address?");
              email=k.next();
              System.out.print("What is your phone number?");
             pno=k.nextInt();
             System.out.print("How many children do you have?");
             nochild=k.nextInt();
             System.out.print("You are Alan " + surname);
              System.out.println();





             int childcounter=1;
            do{
              System.out.print("What is your childs first name "+childcounter+" of " +nochild+"?");
              cfn=k.next();
              System.out.print("What is "+cfn+"'s age?");
              cage=k.nextInt();
              System.out.println();
              do {
              System.out.print("What is the title of the book "+cfn+" would like?");
              btitle=k.next();      
              System.out.print("Price of '"+btitle+"' ?");
             price=k.nextDouble();
              System.out.println();


              System.out.print("Do you want to finish? y/n ");
              finished=k.next();





              }
             while (finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));


            if (finished.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {

            }
              childcounter++;
            }
        while (childcounter <= nochild);
            System.out.print("Heres the book price €"+price);
            }
```

Comment: You need to use an Array.

Comment: You really need to format your code properly (use IDE which can format the code for you...). Especially if you are a beginner, you should not try to make things harder for you by having messy code... Especially when nicely formatted code is just a few mouse or key clicks away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
String[][] data = new String[numberOfLoops][numberOfVariable];
```

so you can use

```
data[nthIteration][variable] = scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

To have variables persist through a loop, you need to define them before the loop begins. If a variable is defined inside of a loop, it will be deleted once the loop is finished.

```
    int test;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test = test * i;
    }
    //test's value will persist
```

Tutorial: [`Java >> Variable Scope`](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

---

If you want to store multiple values into a variable, you should look at Arrays

Tutorial: [`Java >> Arrays`](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Arrays.cfm#.UokVVcSsi7s)

Comment: What I am trying to do is have a variable that I can keep adding too until I want to print out the combined total, is that possible?

Comment: I see it, now. Your problem is the fact that you put `childcounter++;` outside of the **do-while** loop. Put it inside and your int shall increment correctly. Edit: I'm wrong, it's just very hard to read your code due to the lack of proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to define a class that contains those variables/fields:

```
public class MyInfo {
  String surname, firstname, email, cfn, btitle, finished;
  double pno, nochild, cage, noboks, costbook=0, totalcost, averagecost, price;
}
```

then create new instance of the class on each iteration of the while loop and store each new object in a list/ArrayList